# Is there way to get attachments details before starting the workflow?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Before I start the business process, I select the attachments. I can do it many times, remove attachments and choose again.

I want to display dynamic table with information about attachments.

For example, to retrieve all the attachments details, I use such code:

```
...
var divWithAnchors = YAHOO.util.Selector.query("#page_x002e_data-form_x002e_task-details_x0023_default_assoc_packageItems-cntrl")[0];
var anchors = divWithAnchors.getElementsByTagName('a');

var attachments = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    attachments[i] = anchors[i].href.split('=')[1];
}
...
```

It gives me references to nodes, for example:

```
...
workspace://SpacesStore/c5a27463-c2aa-4c70-aca7-1f999d3ac76a
workspace://SpacesStore/29e9f035-403c-47b6-8421-624d584ff7eb
workspace://SpacesStore/712aaca2-9c90-4733-a690-bbf9bacb26e6
workspace://SpacesStore/68893fde-ee7c-4ecb-a2df-d4953dc69439
...
```

Then I can do AJAX requests to the REST back-end (WebScripts) and get the responses:

```
...
for(var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
    Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonGet(
    ...
    // parse JSON and fill the table
```

Is this the correct way? I'm not sure about the ID:

```
page_x002e_data-form_x002e_task-details_x0023_default_assoc_packageItems-cntrl
```

Is this a constant?.. Can this identifier be changed?

Comment: what kind of information you need to display in page for node?

Comment: As of now, it will work... But I hope very soon alfresco may be moving this page to aikau style and there is a chance of code break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, all these NodeRefs are available in the object `selectedItems = {}` and can be obtained in the method `getAddedItems()` (see `object-finder.js`):

```
...

/**
* Selected items. Keeps a list of selected items for correct Add button state.
* 
* @property selectedItems
* @type object
*/
selectedItems: null,

...

/**
* Returns items that have been added to the current value
*
* @method getAddedItems
* @return {array}
*/
getAddedItems: function ObjectFinder_getAddedItems() {
    var addedItems = [],
    currentItems = Alfresco.util.arrayToObject(this.options.currentValue.split(","));

    for (var item in this.selectedItems) {
        if (this.selectedItems.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            if (!(item in currentItems)) {
                addedItems.push(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return addedItems;
},

...
```

Next, is needed to send these NodeRefs to the WebScript and get all the necessary properties by using `NodeService` service.